# CSS Transition - I want the black border to slide left and right smoothly on clicking any of the two options

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here I have two separate options - Friends and Service Providers. I want the black border to slide left and right smoothly on clicking any of the two options.
When I click on 'service providers', the black bottom border must slide smoothly towards right. When I click on 'Friends', it should slide smoothly towards left.
I want to achieve this with CSS transitions may be.

Kindly help! I shall be grateful.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px
}

.row {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  margin: 0px;
}

.friends.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 friends active">
      <h6>Friends</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 seller">
      <h6>Service Providers</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Heading elements are not intended to be clickable like this. You should be using [tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#tabs) or a [button group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/button-group), maybe. Semantic markup is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the radio button hack to fake it. I would also just use another element as the one that moves.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px
}

.row {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  margin: 0px;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  transition: all .5s;
}

#friendBox:checked~span {
  left: 0%;
}

#sellerBox:checked~span {
  left: 50%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="radio" id="friendBox" name="header"></input>
    <input type="radio" id="sellerBox" name="header"></input>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 friends active">
      <label for="friendBox">Friends</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 seller">
      <label for="sellerBox">Service Providers</label>
    </div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution, but if OP is using Bootstrap this isn't necessary.

Comment: Also if you want to animate it by clicking anywhere in the text area vice clicking the text itself then you can set your label widths and heights to 100% ```label {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }```

Comment: Justin, your solutions should be in your answer, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can place an HR in your row and then animate the position using margin-left. On hover use the general sibling selector ~ with pseudo :hover to select the HR element. Adding a transition to the HR with margin duration and ease will animate its margin when the element is hovered over.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px
}

.row {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 2.2rem; /* added to make more visually appealing */
}

.friends, .seller {
  cursor: pointer; /* added to show these are links */
  height: 1.2rem; /* added to make more visually appealing */
}

.friends:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 0%; /* placement of HR should be below friends btn */
}

.seller:hover ~ hr {
  margin-left: 50%; /* placement of HR should be below seller btn */
}

hr {
  height: .15rem;
  width: 50%; /* width will be width of row (block ~ 100%) / # of btns */
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
  border: none;
  transition: margin .3s ease-in-out; /* Transition for the margin movement */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 friends active">
      <h4>Friends</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 seller">
      <h4>Service Providers</h4>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```